# Replacing np.inf and -np.inf values with maximum and minimum of a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some `-np.inf` and `np.inf` values in my dataframe.
I would like to replace them with the respective minimum and maximum values of the dataframe.

I thought it should be possible with something like this:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], [df.max, df.min], axis=1, inplace = True)
```

But it didn't work. I had the idea because I can use something similar to replace nans with `fillna()`.

What is an effective way to go about it?

Is there a numpy version?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), as follows:

```
df = df.replace({np.inf: df[np.isfinite(df)].max().max(), 
                -np.inf: df[np.isfinite(df)].min().min()})
```

Here, `df[np.isfinite(df)].max().max()` and `df[np.isfinite(df)].min().min()` are the respective finite maximum and minimum of the dataframe. We replace `np.inf` and `-np.inf` with them respectively.

**Demo**

**Data Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [np.inf, -2000.0, 345.0], 'Col2': [1234.0, -np.inf, 890.0]})


     Col1    Col2
0     inf  1234.0
1 -2000.0    -inf
2   345.0   890.0
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

     Col1    Col2
0  1234.0  1234.0
1 -2000.0 -2000.0
2   345.0   890.0
```

#### Edit

If you want to replace with min max of the particular column instead of the min max over the global dataframe, you can use nested dict in [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), as follows:

```
col_min_max = {np.inf: df[np.isfinite(df)].max(),    # column-wise max
              -np.inf: df[np.isfinite(df)].min()}    # column-wise min

df = df.replace({col: col_min_max for col in df.columns})
```

**Demo**

**Data Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [np.inf, -2000.0, 345.0], 'Col2': [1234.0, -np.inf, 890.0]})


     Col1    Col2
0     inf  1234.0
1 -2000.0    -inf
2   345.0   890.0
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)

     Col1    Col2
0   345.0  1234.0
1 -2000.0   890.0
2   345.0   890.0
```

**`inf` and `-inf` are replaced by the respective max, min *of the column* accordingly.**

Comment: Oh thanks, nice! Another way! Is it possible to replace with min max of the particular column or just the min max over the global dataframe?

Comment: @Olli  Good question!  You can use nested dict in `.replace()`.  Let me show you.

Comment: @Olli  See my edit above.

Comment: @Olli  Further revised the code so that we no longer need to manually quote column names.  Automated by dict comprehension.  Take a look.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much @SeaBean, such a nice solution!

Comment: sorry to pester you, I just tried the above but got the following error:
ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Would you know what this means by chance?

Edit: hmm, I think it's probably about string columns, though the boolean mask returns ints as NANs

Comment: @Olli  That's right, it is owing to the non-numeric columns there.  For non-numeric columns, all other solutions here simply don't support alike and raise some other kinds of error e,g. `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'` or `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @Olli  If your dataframe is mixed with non-numeric columns, suggest you to work only on the  numeric columns (otherwise, min/max is just meaningless).  You can do so by e.g. use  `df1 = df.select_dtypes('number')` to define `df1` as a subset of the numeric columns and work on `df1` on subsequent operations.  Good luck!   Let me know if any other question.

Comment: thanks that worked, I was able to do it, in a slightly less elegant way but the same idea. Will change to yours, thanks again!

Comment: @Olli  Glad it works for you!  Thanks for your appreciation and support!  :-)

Comment: @Olli How's going with changing to my codes?  Work fine ?

Comment: yes, worked like a charm and actually my preferred solution because I understand it better, thanks so much!

Comment: I did that, now, I felt a little bad because I had already accepted another solution, but I it makes sense that if someone comes with the same problem and previous knowledge as me he will likely prefer your solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) which takes boolean series or dataframes, which you can then get with [`np.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html) for example.

```
>>> df
     0
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  inf
3  2.0
4 -inf
5  3.0
>>> posinf = df.gt(0) & df.transform(np.isinf)
>>> neginf = df.lt(0) & df.transform(np.isinf)
>>> df = df.mask(posinf, df.mask(posinf).max().max())
>>> df = df.mask(neginf, df.mask(neginf).min().min())
>>> df
     0
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  3.0
3  2.0
4  0.0
5  3.0
```

I’m masking twice, the inner call has no replacing value so it replaces with `NaN`. This allows to then compute the min/max bounds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, both your answers were equally helpful, I'm going to accept @mozaways answer as it has a little more detail on the per column version. cheers!

Comment: No worries @Olli they’re sensibly the same answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute [`masks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for inf/-inf and replace with the values you want:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = df.eq(np.inf)
m2 = df.eq(-np.inf)

df.mask(m1, df[~m1].max().max()).mask(m2, df[~m2].min().min()))
```

*NB. this will replace the inf with the min/max for the whole dataframe, if you want to take the min/max **per column**:*

```
df.mask(m1, df[~m1].max(), axis=1).mask(m2, df[~m2].min(), axis=1)
```

input:

```
   col
0  inf
1  1.0
2 -inf
3  2.0
4  NaN
```

output:

```
   col
0  2.0
1  1.0
2  1.0
3  2.0
4  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, the per column version is what I'd like to do. Cheers!